# StackExchange.Redis - MISCONF Redis randomly fails to save to RDB Snapshot

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I have implemented StackExchange.Redis in my application and overall it works pretty well.  However we randomly get the following error.

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, 
but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are 
disabled. Please check Redis logs for details about the error.
```

I ran the `CONFIG SET dir` and `CONFIG SET dbfilename` and confirmed that it is able to save the file without issues in the C:\Temp folder.

So I'm looking for direction on this.  Do I catch the error and swallow it?  Do I catch the error and retry the save of data?  Is there some other solution?

Please do not recommend `config set stop-writes-on-bgsave-error` no this is not a solution, it is turning off something you really should have on.

Our database size is not that big, it is 410 items, though some of the strings are really large (7MB is the biggest).  But most are just the cache of a very basic html blocks.

Answer (score 0):

As of this answer I have no answers on this topic so I had to make an effort to at least gracefully handle the error.

I wrapped the SET in a try catch, upon error I sleep for 5 seconds and do it again.  If that fails I throw the error.

```
try
{
    var pending = _redisDb.StringSetAsync(key, value, time);
    _redisDb.Wait(pending);
}
catch
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    var pending = _redisDb.StringSetAsync(key, value, time);
    _redisDb.Wait(pending);
}
```

So if the server is really down and having issues I still get the error, but at the time it gets these hiccups I sleep and let it catch up.  So far no errors with this new code.

I do not know if this is recommended (lack of answers), but it works.